# using props in react to bring data from mongodb and set it in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to bring in data from mongodb to display on my home screen a list of products. using react and 3 components Home.tsx, PizzaList.tsx, PizzaCard.tsx. I'm using usestate hook and useEffect hook. I am getting this error in the browser console. react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. followed by Check the render method of `PizzaList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information. as you can see in the code I have a key in pizzaList on pizzaCard component.

Home.tsx

```
import Featured from "./Featured";
import PizzaList from "./PizzaList";
import { getPizzaList } from "../components/api";

export default function Home() {
  const [product, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      title: "",
      desc: "",
      img: "",
      price: "",
      extraOptions: "",
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPizzaList()
      .then((items) => {
        console.log("====data+++", items);
        setProducts(items);
      })
      .catch((Error) => {
        console.error(Error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Featured />
      <PizzaList PizzaList={product} />
      Home
    </div>
  );
}
```

PizzaList.tsx

```
import PizzaCard from "./PizzaCard";

const PizzaList = ({ PizzaList }: any) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>THE BEST PIZZA IN TOWN</h1>
      <p className={styles.desc}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut blandit arcu
        in pretium molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames acme. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        {PizzaList.map((pizzas: any) => (
          <PizzaCard key={pizzas._id} title={pizzas.title} desc={pizzas.desc} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PizzaList;
```

PizzaCard.tsx

````
// import pizza from "../img/pizza.png";
const PizzaCard = ({ pizza }: any) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <img src={pizza.img} alt="" width="200" height="200" />
      <h1 className={styles.title}>{pizza.title}</h1>
      <span className={styles.price}>${pizza.prices[0]}</span>
      <p className={styles.desc}>{pizza.desc}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PizzaCard;```
````

Comment: I think the error is props "pizza" is undefined in PizzaCard component. You are not passing any props pizza from pizzaList component

Comment: Could you post the `getPizzaList` code as well so that we can check whether it returns the `_id` property as expected?

Comment: what would that look like?

Comment: export async function getPizzaList() {
  return await fetch("http://localhost:4000/products").then((data) =>
    data.json()
  );
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function second argument which basically returns current index of array, so we have unique number on every iteration of data.

```
import PizzaCard from "./PizzaCard";

const PizzaList = ({ PizzaList }: any) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>THE BEST PIZZA IN TOWN</h1>
      <p className={styles.desc}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut blandit arcu
        in pretium molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames acme. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        {PizzaList.map((pizzas: any, index:number) => (
          <PizzaCard key={index} title={pizzas.title} desc={pizzas.desc} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PizzaList;
```

Comment: now i get PizzaCard.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at PizzaCard (PizzaCard.js:4:1)

Comment: I think it warning comes in IDE and IDE sometime take time to understand usage of parameter and variable. Have you get key error in browser?

Comment: no more key error

Comment: So you IDE will solved this after some time, it's due to sometime your IDE slow and doesn't find where parameter and variable are using.

Hope you main error are solved.